# PyQt4 and pyuic4

Tags: python, pyqt

I'm trying to compile my first .ui file using PyQt4 on a mac with osx 10.6. I'm getting a syntax error and I'm not sure what it means.

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/Users/womble/Dropbox/scratch/')
>>> from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
>>> pyuic4 Urb.ui > Urb.py

File "<stdin>", line 1
    pyuic4 Urb.ui > Urb.py
             ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried adding

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.5
```

as my first line to the .ui file and I still get the same problem.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're mixing Python and shell commands.

This is Python code and can be executed from an interactive Python session:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/womble/Dropbox/scratch/')
from PyQt4 import QtCore, QtGui
```

This is supposed to be run from a command prompt or terminal window.  It's giving syntax errors in your Python interpreter because it's not Python:

```
pyuic4 Urb.ui > Urb.py
```

Answer (score 2):

I normally use `pyuic4` [from the command line](http://www.opendocs.net/pyqt/pyqt4.html#pyuic4) in the following way:

```
pyuic4 -xo Urb.py Urb.ui
```

The `x` flag makes sure the generated Python code includes a small amount of additional code that creates and displays the GUI when it is executes as a standalone application.

The `o` flag specifies the output file to write to (in the example above: Urb.py)

Answer (score 0):

After spending almost 6 hours on finding the right solution, the steps on this page is by far the most accurate that worked perfectly on my mac 10.6.8

http://www.pythonsummerschool.net/index.php?url=mac_pyqt

I can now convert *.ui files to *.py files seamlessly on terminal:

Once you have pyQt configured with sip and all relevant dependencies as described on this link, you have to go to /Applications/Python 3.2/Update Shell Profile.command and run it.

Check your path variables:
env | grep PATH

Once everything is pointing to your latest Python install then you can double check by running /Applications/Python 3.2/Update Shell Profile.command

Then its as easy as 
pyuic4 /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/yourfile.ui > /Volumes/BOOTCAMP/yourfile.py

Have fun!